# why is my retry with timeout get undefine result

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to implement retry with timeout, even though I'm using await for every function call, the result I got back from line 2 is still undefined

I tried to use async.retry() package to handle retry, but ran into similar issue.

```
let result = await retry(5, handleAPI, handleReponse, [200], URL, "GET");
console.log("result == " + result); // undefined


function handleReponse(body) {
    return body.id;
}


// handle retry
async function retry(retryCount, functionToRetry, callback, validStatusCode, ...args) {
    async function attempt() {
        if (retryCount != 0) {
          retryCount--;
          var response = await functionToRetry(...args);
          const { statusCode, body } = response;
          if (validStatusCode.includes(statusCode)) {
            const res = callback(body);
            console.log("res of callback is " + res); // it logged correct result here
            return res;
          } else {
                setTimeout(attempt(), 1000); // wait 1000ms to retry
          }

        }
        throw new Error('unsuccesfully.');
    }
    attempt();
}

// handle api
async function handleAPI(URL,  type){
    console.log('URL is', URL);
    const response = await httpClient(URL, {
        method: type,
        json: true,
    })
    .then(response => {
    const { statusCode, body } = response;
    console.log(' response statusCode: ', statusCode);
    // console.log('response body: ', body);
    return response;
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(' Api call error: ', err);
    });

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're returning value from `attempt()` but not from `retry()`, to avoid such scenarios use `Promise`. And for repetitive task use setInterval, as below:

```
async function retry(retryCount, functionToRetry, callback, validStatusCode, ...args) {
return await new Promise((res, rej) => {
    var interval = setInterval(() => attempt(), 1000);
    function attempt() {
        if (retryCount != 0) {
            retryCount--;
            var response = await functionToRetry(...args);
            const { statusCode, body } = response;
            if (validStatusCode.includes(statusCode)) {
                const result = callback(body);
                console.log("res of callback is " + res); // it logged correct result here
                clearInterval(interval);
                res(result);
            }
        }
        clearInterval(interval);
        rej();
        throw new Error('unsuccesfully.');
    }
})
```

}

Comment: thanks, but my test case doesn't actually retry, which means there are other bugs

Comment: Haha, sometimes we do complex things very simple and simple one complex.

Comment: yeah, I'm a java dev, not used to debugging in js. Thanks for the help

Comment: `var response = await functionToRetry(...args);` is still causing me issue :( I can't have await in not async function, how do I make my promise async?

Comment: async function attempt() {